# Removing any content after .com/ in python string

Tags: python, string, url

I'm trying to remove content after .com/ in a python string to grab just a domain name.
I've tried to use split however it splits the url as so:

```
'example', '.com/', 'examplestring'
```

Any idea on how to delete everything after ".com/"?
For example, I'd like: example.com/examplestring to become example.com.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Is it not acceptable to simply join the first two elements of that result?

Answer (score 0):

First split the string by `.com` and then join the first part of `splits` with `'.com'`.

```
s = "example.com/examplestring"
splits = s.split('.com')
output = splits[0] + '.com'
print(output)
```

Output:

```
'example.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what the general case is here but if you don't have the protocol (http:// or http://) you could try

```
"""example.com/examplestring""".split('/')[0]
```

if you do have the protocol you can do split on '.com/' but that assumes you all your urls are .com.